# How do you call a Moodle webservice from a block/mod plugin?

Tags: jquery, ajax, moodle

Perhaps this is a simple question but I am not quite sure how to use Moodle's AJAX example code for web services within Blocks and other plugins on the front end.

So, here is the example code that was given for AJAX:

```
require(['core/ajax'], function(ajax) {
    var promises = ajax.call([
        { methodname: 'core_get_string', args: { component: 'mod_wiki', stringid: 'pluginname' } },
        { methodname: 'core_get_string', args: { component: 'mod_wiki', stringid: 'changerate' } }
    ]);

   promises[0].done(function(response) {
       console.log('mod_wiki/pluginname is' + response);
   }).fail(function(ex) {
       // do something with the exception
   });

   promises[1].done(function(response) {
       console.log('mod_wiki/changerate is' + response);
   }).fail(function(ex) {
       // do something with the exception
   });
});
```

So, is this encapsulated inside another call, like a click() event?

How would I use this example or other web services like it on the front end of a Moodle theme, blog, or other module?